# Not receiving peripheral discovery callback with CoreBluetooth (iPhone 6)

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to connect to 2 BLE peripherals then discover their services.

If I'm **not paired** to them, it works fine, and I can repeat this action as many times as I want.
However, if I get **paired** to them, after a few amount of tries to connect then discover them (around 10, it varies), I don't receive the CoreBluetooth callback:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?)
```

The situtation is always changing this way:

- I receive the callbacks for both peripherals
- I lose the callback for one peripheral, but not the other
- I lose the callback for both peripherals

I noticed that as soon as I clear my paired devices list, it works fine again.

I feel like this may be related to some caching of the services, but I can't find much informations about that. Should I check the cache before starting a discovery?

What I've tried:

- Turning off/on BLE
- Restarting the phone
- Restarting the peripherals

**EDIT :**

When one of the device is failing to be discovered, any third party app also fails to discover it. I tried [LightBlue](https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/lightblue-explorer-bluetooth/id557428110?mt=8) and [BLE Discovery](https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/ble-discovery/id821826273?mt=8).

**EDIT 2:**

This bug does not show up on iPhone 5S and 6S+.

Comment: After doing a full factory reset, the problem went away for a couple of tries and then came back...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, the devices are indeed showing up, but with a different name.

I was working with BLE devices that had one advertising name different from the GAP name. Thus, before connecting the first time to a device I could see his advertising name in the scan result, but once I got connected to it, it was his GAP name who showed up in the scan result (I believe it was cached by iOS).

I could not figure that out quickly because I was working in an environnement with a lot a BLE devices.